# Serial Downvotes are not reversed for Helpful Flag

Tags: discussion, flags, downvotes, moderation

Intentional Downvotes: 4 Questions with **positives score** has been *downvoted*, If we look at the time of downvotes It seems like it has been done the same user *intentionally*. I have waited for 24 hours for script to run which may rollback that downvotes but nothing happened. So I flagged one of my questions for needing moderator attention which has been marked as ***helpful*** (means questions has been downvotes by the same user) so I thought that downvotes will be role backed soon but it was not.

- Will the downvotes be rollbacked? If yes, how much time will it need?
- Or it was not done by the same user (might be a conflict with helpful flag)

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to moderators and CM, serial voting has been rollbacked yesterday (10 Days).

[image]

Comment: What's best in this scenario is to regain back that same reputation as soon as you've been serial downvoted. By this, you will contribute more to the site and show the people who've downvoted that this doesn't affect you and that -6 was done for nothing

Comment: @weegee, Yes I will contribute, but some action should be taken against them who are doing this kind of thing for revenge

Comment: @PatelRomil since your question has an answer you should avoid changing it such that the answer is no longer valid. Feel free to ask other separate questions to elicit other answers. There are probably existing questions and answers on this subject that it would be worth searching for/researching first though.

Comment: @PatelRomil this question is closed so although you'd really like to change it and get further answers that's not really going to be possible on this question. As I said before, another question is the way to go if you can't find the answers here already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The moderator who handled your flag has sent off a message to the Community Team. Moderators do not have the power to reverse votes, but will sent the Team the appropriate information for investigation. Beyond that we have no control over whether the Team will reverse the votes or not.

It can take the Team a couple of weeks to catch up with backlog requests to look at users' accounts. We make multiple requests of them every day.

Patience is key.

Comment: It's also important to note that nothing may come of this; they may do their investigation and find out nothing untoward is going on.

Comment: Moderator may need to have the rights to handle such kind of things. May I ask why even moderators do not have the rights to handle serial downvoting. Or do we need to improve our script which should be able to detect a downvoting pattern and roll back it

Comment: @PatelRomil votes are by definition anonymous. So the users nor the mods can see who upvoted or downvoted. But the CM's can see who voted

Comment: @PatelRomil Vote reversal is a sensitive topic, we take votes and their anonymity seriously. Even moderators cannot see who votes for what, and that is by design. For this reason, an employee with stronger privileges needs to look at it. If you have more questions (or a suggestion to change this), I propose you post it in a new post here on meta. (I will say that I don't think that's a good use of your time, it's not likely to change anytime soon)

Comment: Any specific time indication? I've got a helpful flag on suspicious voting behaviour from the 21st of july and the voting is still occurring today, it's one devoted individual. The usual 6-8?

Comment: I'm assuming the auto-reversal is broken. I've been serially upvotes (batches of 3 votes for a long time), which didn't get reversed after a third mod flag. Three downvotes are usually reversed though, but I've had serial downvotes that didn't get reversed either. Mod-flagged another batch yesterday (took two flags to convince instant escalation, but I have no idea if it was or not). It would be nice to have some transparency here - link the flag and let it show the status when it's been escalated, so a pending serial voting flag says `helpful - pending employee review` (1/2)

Comment: And something similar when it's been reviewed by an employee. A public estimation of backlog size would also be nice, and beats guesstimating 6-8 arbitrary time units

Comment: I went ahead and [posted a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332009/332043) on the flag status.

Comment: Great @Zoe, some status should be there atleast